# Redirect secured by Keycloak client side apps to login page after idle timeout. Apps are behind app gateway

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, redhat-sso

How to implement logout of client side services after idle timeout?

Services are secured by Keycloak + Application gateway.

The Gateway is node.js app which protects services' urls using [Keycloak node.js adapter](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect), so that authentication will be required on browser access to the urls. (redirect to login url)

Services enforce authorization locally by inspecting roles present in the access token gateway receives and attaches to the request after successful authentication.

Keycloak is behind gateway too.

I thought about adding [custom event listener](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_events) in Keycloak code which would notify all the services interested in session timeout event via some message bus.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak informs all clients participating in a session that gets terminated (by timeout or explicit logout request). The only prerequisite is that the "Admin URL" is set for the client (see Keycloak admin console - client settings).
Since you're using the Keycloak node.js adapter it should be able to handle the logout request from Keycloak.
See [Keycloak Server Administration Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#oidc-clients) (look for "Admin URL").

Comment: Thats right. For testing described backchannel requests you could use "Revocation" tab at client page in Admin UI. At this tab you could push revocation request to client backend, so you can trace this request to be sure that everything working well. Other approach is to perform sessions logout from Admin UI.